# swift dragUP navigation

Tags: swift, swipe, drag

I'm totally new to coding and was already very happy to get swipe down functionality into my app.

Now I would like to have a swipe up, so if I drag it down I have a UIView that can have some sort of navigation/option screen (all that code is working perfectly) but I want it the other way around (so you can see that it's down there and then you'd swipe it up). I followed a tutorial online that showed me how to get it like this and after I implemented the first code it's already up there and I tried a couple of things but I don't seem to get it.. here's the code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var myview:myView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        myview = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("customView", owner: self, options: nil).last as signUpView
        myview.frame = CGRectMake(0, -self.view.frame.size.height + 66, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)

        self.view.addSubview(signup)

        myview.setup()
```

Comment: Where is the code that you use to detect swipe down?

Comment: But i dont understand why the code in my question makes a rectangle above in the screen. could you tell me that? @iosDev82?